# SQL Server - Looking for a way to shorten code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm basically very new to SQL Server, so please bare with me. Here is my problem:
I have a table with (let's say) 10 columns and 80k rows. I have 1 column called Date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD type varchar(50) (can't convert it to date or datetime type I tried, the initial source of data is not good).

**Example :

Table [dbo].[TestDates]

| Code | SellDate |
| --- | --- |
| XS4158 | 2019-11-26 |
| DE7845 | 2020-02-06 |

What I need to do is to turn the YYYY-MM-DD format to DD/MM/YYYY format. After a lot of tries (I tried the functions (DATE_FORMAT, CONVERT, TO_DATE etc) and this is solution :

1- I added a primary key for join purpose later (ID)
2- I split my date column in 3 columns in a whole new table
3- I merged the 3 columns in the order I need with the delimiter of my choice (/) in the same new table
4- I copied the good column to my initial table using the primary key ID I created before

```
alter table [dbo].[TestDates]
add ID int not null IDENTITY primary key;

SELECT ID,
FORMAT(DATEPART(month, [SellDate]),'00') AS Month, 
FORMAT(DATEPART(day, [SellDate]),'00') AS Day, 
FORMAT(DATEPART(year, [SellDate]),'0000') AS Year 
INTO [dbo].[TestDates_SPLIT]
FROM [dbo].[TestDates]
GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDates_SPLIT]
 ADD SellDate_OK varchar(50)

 UPDATE [dbo].[TestDates_SPLIT]
 SET SellDate_OK = [Day] + '/' + [Month] + '/' + [Year]

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDates_SPLIT]
 DROP COLUMN Month, Day, Year

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestDates]
 ADD SellDate_GOOD varchar(50)

 UPDATE [dbo].[TestDates] 
 SET [TestDates].SellDate_GOOD = [TestDates_SPLIT].SellDate_OK
 FROM [dbo].[TestDates]
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[TestDates_SPLIT] 
 ON [TestDates].ID = [TestDates_SPLIT].ID
```

This code works but i find too heavy and long, considering I have 6 more dates columns to work on. Is there a way to make it shorter or more efficient? Maybe with SET SellDate = SELECT (some query of sorts that doesn't require to create and delete table)

Thank you for your help

I tried the usual SQL functions but since my column is a varchar type, the converting was impossible

Comment: " I have 1 column called Date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD type varchar(50) " - there's your first problem.

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes I believe it's a problem, but the data source is corrupt like that I believe, I get the data from one internal app we use at work, all the files are .txt and there are a lot of bugs in it

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing dates as text.  But, that being said, we can try doing a rountrip conversion from text `YYYY-MM-DD` to date to text `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT '2022-11-08' AS dt
)

SELECT dt,                                                    -- 2022-11-08
       CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, dt, 121), 103)  -- 08/11/2022
FROM cte;
```

### Demo

Comment: Can I apply this for the whole column?  (SELECT [SellDate] AS dt) ?

Comment: Yes, I assume your date column is called `dt` for simplicity.  BTW...you should be storing _dates_ in a _date_ column.  Then call `CONVERT()` when you want to view those dates in a certain output format.

Comment: For my work I get the data from an internal app as .txt file, then I import the data (flat source file) to SQL Server, and the date columns are automatically varchar(50) in SQL and I can't convert them to Date format (Error)

Comment: There should be no error if your text dates are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.  What is the error?

Comment: I did this : 
 WITH cte AS (
 SELECT [VALUE_DATE] AS dt FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
)
SELECT dt,                                                    
CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, dt, 121), 103)  
FROM cte;

And got this error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: You most likely have bad text dates in your table.  To find those values, run `SELECT VALUE_DATE FROM MyTable WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime, VALUE_DATE) IS NULL`